# Django 1.8 EmailField now accepts invalid email addresses

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.8 model `EmailField` like so...

```
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

...allows invalid emails to be entered. For example the following creates a valid user when should error...

> User(email="number_six@caprica", password="xyz")

However, if I test the validator in Django it correctly catches it...

> from django.core.validators import validate_email
>   validate_email("number_six@caprica")

I get the correct `Enter a valid email address.` responce.

So whats going on? Does `EmailField` and `validate_email` not use the same regex? Why does `EmailField` accept invalid email addresses where `validate_email` does not?

Comment: EmailField does use the validate_email method. Perhaps it is called when you try to save the object?

Comment: @IonutHulub the above was tested directly in Shell where EmailField allows it and validate_email does not. To me there is something odd going on here.

Comment: Perhaps the validaters are invoken when you save the object to the database. Try `email.save()` and see if that throws a validation error.

Comment: @IonutHulub Nope tried ``User(email="number_six@capricaa", password="xyz").save()`` which still saves to the DB. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not invalid email addresses, browsers accept those too in inputs of type email.

`me@localhost` for example is a valid email address.

Local domain names do not require a [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), that is why.

**Edit:** although these are valid email addresses, Django does not accept them. `EmailField` does use the `validate_email` validator.

Your issue is that model instances validation has to be run manually, using the `full_clean` method for example. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects for more information.

Comment: So then why does EmailField accept an invalid email addresses where validate_email does not?

Comment: @OrbiterFleet it does not. Validators are not run when instantiating an object. Then need to be ran manually.

Comment: Does the clean method not get called in .save() automatically?

Comment: @OrbiterFleet No, it does get called when using `ModelForm.save` though.

Comment: No sure I fully understand why save() and .save so different things but that appears to work.